# In rails, how can I find out what caused a .save() to fail, other than validation errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord model which is returning `true` from `valid?` (and .errors is empty), but is returning `false` from `save()`.  If the model instance is valid, how can I find out what's causing the save to fail?

Comment: I had this problem a couple of weeks ago. Some refactoring had left a before_save function returning false all the time, which causes save to fail.

Comment: @Jeff -- thanks, it turns out that there was a :before_save method returning false.  How did you find out?  Was it just code inspection?

Comment: It was code inspection, and doing diffs against version control.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Check all your callbacks.

I had a problem like this where I had and "after_validate" method that was failing after I had made a bunch of changes to the model. The model was valid but the "after_validate" was returning false, so if I used `model.valid` it said true, but then if I saved it gave me validation errors (passed through from the after_validate callback). It was weird.

Look at the application trace and you should be able to see what line of code is raising the exception.

Comment: As per Jeff's comment, the problem turned out to be a before_save callback returning false.

Comment: @kdt - that's exactly what my problem was. I hadn't thought about it because the before_save was just meant to set a property, but because it was setting it to a false value, that was implicitly returned and that made the save fail silently. On the bright side, I now have the option of fixing this code by adding the line `"Hey! That's MY fake leg!" # Believe it or not, this is important`. Not that I would do that. ;)

Comment: A nice way to ensure a true return value is `true.tap { do_something }`

Comment: wow, what an obscure issue. Would never have guesses that a callback returning false would have stopped saving. Could someone point me to the docs on this? Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @andy http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#halting-execution

Comment: Rails 5.something docs look different - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#halting-execution so looks like this was fixed/improved. Compare https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_record_callbacks.html#halting-execution

Answer (score 147):

If `@user.save` (for example) returns `false`, then just run this to get all the errors:

```
@user.errors.full_messages
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, .valid? is true -- ie there are no validation errors.  I've checked that .errors is returning an empty list as well (I've updated the question to point that out)

Comment: The sentence returns an Array (**not** String) as of Rails 6.1. For your information.

Answer (score 126):

Try using the bang version `save!` (with an exclamation mark at the end) and inspecting the resulting error.

Comment: save! is just throwing a RecordNotSaved (when I print the .message of the exception I just get the name of the exception class).  Is there somewhere I should be looking for more detail?

Comment: If you're in Rails development mode, it should print a full description of the error with stack trace.  Take a look there for any clues and/or post it here.

Comment: I use the console, load the object (e.g., o = Object.find #id), then do o.save! like the answer says. It prints out why it's not saving.

Comment: FYI, calling `save!` can raise `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` (since it runs validations) or `ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved` so that's what you'll want to rescue.

Comment: I use `creat!` in seeds.rb, but I only got `ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: Failed to save the record` :-(

Comment: +1 because this is the least unsatisfying answer to the fundamental question of how to diagnose `.save` failures that are not due to validation. The "least unsatisfying" qualification refers to Rails, not this answer.

Comment: This helped me because my .valid? was coming back false and I was trying to figure out why and how to debug that. .save! told me my instance needed a date and I didn't have one. Apparently, I accidentally deleted the line that was assigning it. Was able to fix it right up!

Comment: To force seeing the error when the test-framework is not showing the error, a workaround to put the save! in a rescue(e) block, then "puts e.inspect", which got it to show in my console.

Comment: This works! Can you explain what it's doing? (so we can understand how you knew to try that)

Answer (score 3):

Yea, I fixed this issue by making sure I return true in all my before_* callbacks then it starts working :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't trying to save a deleted record.

I had the same issue. But unlike the selected answer - my issue wasn't callbacks related.

In my case I had tried to save to a deleted record (deleted from DB).

```rb
@user = User.new
@user.save! # user saved to DB
@user.persisted? # true

@user.destroy # user deleted from DB
@user.persisted? # false, user still has its id

@user.valid? # return true
@user.errors # empty
@user.save # return false
@user.save! # raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem I had was that I had forgotten to add the validation to the model.

```
class ContactGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```