# User.save coming back as: User Exists => False

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a user and then went `user.save` and got this => false message... I see it says "user exists" but when I go `users = User.all` theres only 1 user I created a little while back that appears. So why is it saying this user exists?

```
irb(main):003:0> user = User.new(:screen_name => "jeff holmes", :email => "jeffholmes@gmail.com", :password => "123456")
/Users/coreyholmes/RubymineProjects/worklink/app/models/user.rb:22: warning: regular expression has ']' without escape: /\A[A-Z0-9._%-]+@(A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}\z/
=> #<User id: nil, screen_name: "jeff holmes", email: "jeffholmes@gmail.com", password: "123456">
irb(main):004:0> user.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`screen_name` = BINARY 'jeff holmes' LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'jeffholmes@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
/Users/coreyholmes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.1/lib/active_model/validations/format.rb:8: warning: regular expression has ']' without escape: /\A[A-Z0-9._%-]+@(A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}\z/
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
=> false
```

**UPDATE**
Here is the validation code

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Max and min lengths for all fields
  SCREEN_NAME_MIN_LENGTH = 4
  SCREEN_NAME_MAX_LENGTH = 20
  PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH = 4
  PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH = 20
  EMAIL_MAX_LENGTH = 50
  SCREEN_NAME_RANGE = SCREEN_NAME_MIN_LENGTH...SCREEN_NAME_MAX_LENGTH
  PASSWORD_RANGE = PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH...PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH

  validates_uniqueness_of :screen_name, :email
  validates_length_of :screen_name, :within => SCREEN_NAME_RANGE
  validates_length_of :password, :within => PASSWORD_RANGE
  validates_length_of :email, :maximum => EMAIL_MAX_LENGTH

  validates_format_of :screen_name,
      :with => /\A[A-Z0-9_]*\z/,
      :message => 'must contain only letters, ' + 'numbers, and underscores'

  validates_format_of :email,
      :with => /\A[A-Z0-9._%-]+@(A-Z0-9-+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}\z/,
      :message => 'common... enter a real email address'

end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In rails, how can I find out what caused a .save() to fail, other than validation errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714001/in-rails-how-can-i-find-out-what-caused-a-save-to-fail-other-than-validatio)

Comment: You validation shows that one of your regular expressions is formatted improperly (missing a closing bracket). Follow that error and post the code for that if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Im not sure how to follow the error as I don't understand what the error is. What code should I post?

Comment: What validations are in your User model?

Comment: I added the validations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is part of the problem:

```
/\A[A-Z0-9._%-]+@(A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}\z/
#                ↑
#   Is this supposed to be "(["?
```

P.S. This is also a bad regex for validating an email address. For one thing, there are tons of TLDs with more than four characters now.

Comment: Yes that was part of the problem. I changed it to this and the it helped part of the error.

`/\A[A-Z0-9._%-]+@(A-Z0-9-+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}\z/,`

Comment: I think you want something more like: `/\A[A-Z0-9._%-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}\z/` also what's with the uppercase characters?

Comment: That's definitely not correct, @CoreyHolmes. You need square brackets around a character class. I've updated my answer, having realized that the `(` was correct but the `[` was missing.

Comment: well in the book I'm going through it had `/^` at the beginning and `*$/i` at the end. But I changed it to `/\A` and `\z/`. Should it not be uppercase characters?

Comment: You need the `i` flag to indicate a case-insensitive match.

Comment: but either way when I create a user it keeps saying user exists and false so I am unable to `user.save`

Comment: can I go `\z/i`? @jordan

Comment: Yes. Perhaps you should just use the regex the book uses until you've had some time to read up on regular expressions. It seems like you're making arbitrary changes without really understanding what they do.