# Issue adding user through rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application that was done by someone else, who was working before me. I am tasked with gaining access back to this application that was developed using Ruby on Rails. I have never used Ruby on Rails before.

I navigate to the application that was deployed using Heroku, and there's a sign in page. Nobody knows a valid account with credentials so I am forced to figure it out.

First thing I tried was to list all the user accounts by going into the rails console through heroku using `rails c`. I type in `User.all`, I get a `#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`, `User.first` and `User.last` returns `=> nil`. Looks like there are no user accounts registered.

So I try to add in a new account.

I check the attributes for the User model using `User.column_names`.

```
=> ["id", "email", "encrypted_password", "reset_password_token", "reset_password_sent_at", "remember_created_at", "sign_in_count", "current_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "last_sign_in_ip", "created_at", "updated_at", "profile_id", "type", "id_number_id", "checked_status", "checkin_timestamp", "checkout_timestamp", "permissions"]
```

I also checked the view for a user registration in `/views/user/registrations/new.html.erb`. The following snippet tells me that you need `email`, `password` and `password_confirmation` to create a new user.

```
<div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
  </div>
```

So I create a new user as below and get a `false`.

```
user1= User.new
user1.email = "test@example.com"
user1.password = "test123456"
user1.password_confirmation= "test123456"
user1.save

   (1.4ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (1.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'test@example.com' LIMIT 1
   (1.4ms)  ROLLBACK
=> false
```

I have spent quite some time in this, reading documentations, following tutorials and this is how far I have got. I would REALLY appreciate some guidance on what to look at next to help me figure out how to get a working user account so I can log in to this web application from the webpage.

Comment: This will probably help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4714001/3784008

Comment: One question: if app is deployed why you don't you try to add a user from the app itself than from the console ? Also have you checked again `User.last` to make sure you have not been successful once and try to create a new user with the same email address ? Also one thing to check is the User model (in model folder) this is where validation happen. Your password may not be secur enough. Also check the initializers (folder of same name) for `devise.rb`. If your app is using Devise gem, some validations also happen in this file.

Comment: You don't need to use `password_confirmation` on the console. Just encrypt the password and save it to that field. It appears to have a password reset function. You could create a user with a gibberish encrypted password, then go to the sign in page if it has a "forgot my password" link. Or look in the views for a password reset path and check the routes.rb for a password reset route.

Comment: After you do `user.save` you could try `puts user.errors.full_messages.join(', ')`

This will list your validation errors and give you a much better idea what your problem is.

Comment: Doing `user1.save!` will give you the error messages

Comment: Check if there is a user with the email test@example.com already. There might be a uniqueness constraint on email(many authentication plugins put one).

Comment: @AlokSwain The post body explicitly states there are no `User` records: `User.all => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`

Comment: @anothermh - Ah my bad. Thanks for pointing out.